# Android Studio change activity crash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, crash

Activity crash on mobile, but on simulator works, whats wrong? Can anyone help me please?
Its a simple app that show some button than when clicked show a image.
6 Activity

Main Activity

```
package com.example.mobilejoy.kids1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Transições de Cena

        ImageButton toolbar2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon2);
        toolbar2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        ImageButton toolbar3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon3);
        toolbar3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        ImageButton toolbar4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon4);
        toolbar4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FourthActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        ImageButton toolbar5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon5);
        toolbar5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FifthActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        ImageButton toolbar6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon6);
        toolbar6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SixthActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });


        //Evento clicar botão executar audio

        final MediaPlayer first121 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.first121);
        ImageButton imageButton121 = (ImageButton) this.findViewById(R.id.imageButton121);
        imageButton121.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                first121.start();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Second Activity

```
package com.example.mobilejoy.kids1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

/**
 * Created by mobilejoy on 9/13/16.
 */
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        //transição entre cenas

        ImageButton toolbar1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon1);
        toolbar1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        ImageButton toolbar3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon3);
        toolbar3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,ThirdActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        ImageButton toolbar4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon4);
        toolbar4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,FourthActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        ImageButton toolbar5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon5);
        toolbar5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,FifthActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        ImageButton toolbar6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.toolbarIcon6);
        toolbar6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent myIntent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,SixthActivity.class);
                startActivity(myIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mobilejoy.kids1">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.mobilejoy.kids1.SecondActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.mobilejoy.kids1.ThirdActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.mobilejoy.kids1.FourthActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.mobilejoy.kids1.FifthActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.mobilejoy.kids1.SixthActivity"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

End.

Comment: Post the logs from logcat including entire stacktrace please

Comment: Also, what device does it crash on? And what version of Android is that device running?

Comment: do you fixed it ?

Comment: Only in the device the app crash, I already tested in two versions of android.